# How to install apt-get on ChromeOS?

Tags: apt, software-installation, chrome-os

I'm new to Linux. I want to have `apt-get` on my machine, but similar posts suggested to use `wget`, or `dpkg`. I don't have any of those utilities, only `sh`.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I answered, in a general way. What do you really really want? "Having apt-get" is not a final cause. (see comment by roaima - what do you have?, what do you want?)

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak please resist the temptation to put words in the author's mouth.  The default shell is tangential information. It's confusing to me why you would strike out the OP's comment regarding the `sh` shell -- if you think it's extraneous, delete it; otherwise, leave it. I do appreciate updates to grammar and spelling; and the title is definitely an improvement, so thank you for those. If you're not sure what the question is, the correct thing to do is to post a comment to that effect and let the OP respond.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ok, I hoped the OP would respond quick in the comments, but as it appears he merely managed to ask *a* question. I will resist harder next time. Cheers.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I'm so sorry for the late answers

Answer (score 9):

Before you can use Linux commands on a Chrome system, you must enable Linux (beta). It is off by default, because, as the name says, it is beta.

The following steps are taken from the Google documentation, clarified slightly after verifing them on a Chromebook:

- At the bottom right, select the time.
- Select the settings button, indicated by a gear icon.
- Select the settings hamburger menu in the top left.
- Select "Linux (Beta)".
- Under "Linux (Beta)," select Turn On.
- Follow the steps on the screen. Setup can take 10 minutes or more.
- A terminal window opens. You can run Linux commands, install more tools using the APT package manager, and customize your shell.

Comment: I have validated these instructions on my chromebook. 'Settings Settings' is actually two steps. The first is to open the settings menu by selecting the button featuring a gear icon. The second is to select the hamberger menu in the top left of the settings window.

Comment: @Vaelus that sounds a really helpful extra point. You might like to [edit this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/548955/edit) to improve it.

Comment: No. Not the virtual machine. I mean the actual linux shell that runs Chrome OS. (Holding CTRL+ALT+t and typing "shell")